# Issue when trying to invert an array of 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse

I have a simple issue about the inversion of a matrix 4x4, especially when I try to do it with a loop on `integ_prec` indices (`integ_prec = 6` here and `dimBlocks = 4`).

Here is the code snippet :

```
      # Declaration of inverse cross matrix
      invCrossMatrix = np.zeros((dimBlocks,dimBlocks,integ_prec,integ_prec))

      # Build observables covariance matrix
      arrayFullCross_vec = buildObsCovarianceMatrix_vec(k_ref, mu_ref, ir)

      # Invert 4x4 covariance matrix
      for r_p in range(integ_prec):
        for s_p in range(integ_prec):
          invCrossMatrix[:][:][r_p][s_p] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:][:][r_p][s_p])
```

The function `buildObsCovarianceMatrix_vec` returns a 4D array :

```
def buildObsCovarianceMatrix_vec(k_ref, mu_ref, ir):
arrayCrossTemp = np.zeros((dimBlocks,dimBlocks,integ_prec,integ_prec))

... processing

return arrayCrossTemp
```

But I get systematically an error when inversion ocurs :

```
File "GC_forecast_8bins_base_Mpc_DESI_dev.py", line 1345, in integ_LU_cross
    function_A = aux_fun_LU_cross_vec(ecs, way, I1[0], I1[1], I1[2])
  File "GC_forecast_8bins_base_Mpc_DESI_dev.py", line 1216, in aux_fun_LU_cross_vec
    invCrossMatrix[r_p][s_p][:][:] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:][:][r_p][s_p])
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 551, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 97, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

With another version of my code (with scalar values), everything works fine.

I expect to invert a 4x4 matrix at each iteration of loop.

Is the syntax `nvCrossMatrix[:][:][r_p][s_p] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:][:][r_p][s_p]`correct ?

Comment: You can do `np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec)` to invert all the matrices at once, without a loop. If you are getting `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` is because there is one or more matrices that are singular (non-invertible) in your array. You have to decide what you want to do in those cases (or fix the function that generates the matrices if these are supposed to be all invertible).

Comment: @jdehesa shouldn't `arrayFullCross_vec` be reshaped to `(r_p, s_p, 4, 4)` in order to apply broadcasting?

Comment: @jdehesa . Thanks but I jus want to invert a 4x4 matrix indiced by `r_p` and` s_p` (since I have a 4D array) and these 4x4 matrices are contained into `arrayFullCross_vec` 4D array. Do you undertand better the problem ?

Comment: Ah wait no, the problem is surely the syntax, `nvCrossMatrix[:][:][r_p][s_p] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:][:][r_p][s_p]` is not correct, it should probably be `nvCrossMatrix[:, :, r_p, s_p] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:, :, r_p, s_p]`.

Comment: @Brenlla Right I didn't realise the matrix dimensions were the first two ones, thanks. Yes, you could do maybe `np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec.transpose(2, 3, 0, 1)).transpose(2, 3, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Bare `[:]` does nothing.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks, it works with your solution ! why can't we in python numpy use [:][:] instead of [:,:] ? in which case the syntax [:][:] works ? regards

Comment: `[:]` on a NumPy array does nothing, so you can chain as many `[:]` as you want and you will always get the original array again. In your case, `[:][:][r_p][s_p]` means "1-take the whole array; 2-take the whole array; 3-take the `r_p`-th entry of the first dimension of the array (now the array has 3 dimensions); 4-take the `s_p`-th entry of the first dimension of the array (now the array has 2 dimensions)".

Comment: Remember, `numpy` runs within Python.  So `x[:][:][3]` does, `temp=x[:]; temp1=temp[:]; temp2=temp1[3]`.  On the other hand `x[:,:,3]` is one indexing operation, with a tuple argument `(slice(None), slice(None),3)`, which `numpy` iterpretes according to its own well define multidimensional indexing rules.

Comment: @hpaulj . Thanks ! I have done Matlab too much.